# table png file from pandas DF

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

Morning everyone,
I am trying to export a pandas DF as png file.
I am using the code from volodymyr, which works great, but I would like to get the row name as well.
I tried to adapt a bit the code but I can get only an empty column without any row names.

Any suggestion.

```
def render_mpl_table(data, col_width=3.0, row_height=0.625, font_size=14,
                     header_color='#40466e', row_colors=['#f1f1f2', 'w'], edge_color='w',
                     bbox=[0, 0, 1, 1], header_columns=0,header_row=0,
                     ax=None, **kwargs):
    if ax is None:
        size = (np.array(data.shape[::-1]) + np.array([0, 1])) * np.array([col_width, row_height])
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=size)
        ax.axis('off')

    mpl_table = ax.table(cellText=data.values,colLabels=data.columns,rowLabels=data.index, bbox=bbox,**kwargs)

    mpl_table.auto_set_font_size(False)
    mpl_table.set_fontsize(font_size)

    for k, cell in  six.iteritems(mpl_table._cells):
        cell.set_edgecolor(edge_color)
        if k[0] == 0 or k[1] < header_columns:
            cell.set_text_props(weight='bold', color='w')
            cell.set_facecolor(header_color)
        else:
            cell.set_facecolor(row_colors[k[0]%len(row_colors) ])
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig("tabella.png")
    return ax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save the file using bbox_inches tight, now I have the all table with the column and row names.

```
plt.savefig("tabella.png",bbox_inches="tight")
```